# What is the significance of `-1` in Ansible equality comparisons?

Tags: ansible

I am looking through the Ansible documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html) and see the example for registering output as a variable shows this:

```
- name: test play
  hosts: all

  tasks:

      - shell: cat /etc/motd
        register: motd_contents

      - shell: echo "motd contains the word hi"
        when: motd_contents.stdout.find('hi') != -1
```

The equality check in the `when` conditional statement is for -1, but I would have assumed this to be a Boolean value and thus return either a 0 or a 1.  I am unable to find anything in the documentation that points to why the negative case is -1 instead of 0.  This concerns me because it is non-standard behavior, and I'd like to know what other types of return values I can expect in such comparisons, and in any case, what is a success?  A 0?  A 1?

Comment: For future googlers: just use `when: ('hi' in motd_contents.stdout)`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the Python `string.find` method returns `-1` when it cannot find the requested substring.

Otherwise it returns the index where the string was found.

You can refer to the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) :

> `string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
>   Return the lowest index in s where
>   the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in
>   s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.

Comment: I didn't think to check python string methods but it makes perfect sense.  Thanks!